# WebLogic "Application <name> does not have any Components in it."

Tags: java, server, weblogic, weblogic12c, internal-server-error

I have a frequently issue whith my WebLogic, I instaled the WL server on my pc which is a W10 pro, I'm a Java developer and this enviroment is for developing prurposes, well let's talk about the problem.
The issue start after start or restart my WL server, my java applications (EAR, JAR) doesn't work and dont run, the console log show to me this message:
**Application  does not have any Components in it.**

I tried this steps:

1. Uninstall the WebLogic Server then delete all the files located in C:/ Oracle folder then I Reinstaled and configured the server.
2. I uninstaled and reinstaled the NetBeans IDE.

**Note: the version of my WebLogic is 12.2.1.3.0**

I don't have any more ideas to solve this issue. if anyone had this problem and got the solution please help me!! because is disgusting have to install all the apps every mornign when I started my server. And if anyone thoug the application dosent work, the anwser is no, I tried the application in another pc and works, I beleve is the server because when I watch the error I undploy the aplication and then deployed again and my application works correctly.

[Check the console log here!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RjPA.png)

Comment: Check if your application name (eSharedWeb) is not also used by another component like a datasource. If so, rename it and retry to deploy your application.

Comment: Thank u bro that was the problem!!!

Comment: Great, can you accept my answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your application name (eSharedWeb) is not also used by another component like a datasource. If so, rename it and retry to deploy your application.